# Sort arrays that are Hash values

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

I have a hash where the keys are integers and the values are arrays of strings.  I need to then sort the items in the arrays alphabetically and return the sorted array as the new hash value.

I thought something like `hash.map{ |k,v| v.sort }` would work, but, no. Just to be a little more explicit, I need to turn:

```
hash = { 0 => ["c", "d", "b", "a"], 1 => ["e", "q", "x", "m"] }
```

into:

```
hash = { 0 => ["a", "b", "c", "d"], 1 => ["e", "m", "q", "x"] }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way:

```
 hash.each_value { |v| v.sort! }
 #=> {0=>["a", "b", "c", "d"], 1=>["e", "m", "q", "x"]}
```

or more succinctly:

```
hash.each_value(&:sort!)
```

However if you wish to preserve the original hash do this:

```
hash.map { |k,v| [k,v.sort] }.to_h
#=> {0=>["a", "b", "c", "d"], 1=>["e", "m", "q", "x"]}
```

Comment: Nice. Never knew there was an `each_value` method.

Comment: Changed this to accepted answer b/c thoroughness.  #each_value(&:sort!) is probably the most ruby way to do it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
hash.each { |k,v| v.sort! }
```

This sorts the arrays in-place.

Comment: I had tried #each method but I guess the bang on sort! is the important bit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This does not mutate the original hash.

```
hash.merge(hash) { |*,n| n.sort }
  #=> {0=>["a", "b", "c", "d"], 1=>["e", "m", "q", "x"]}
```

If the original hash is to be modified, substitute `merge!` (aka `update`) for `merge`.

This uses the forms of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) and [Hash#merge!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) that employ a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which here is all keys of the original hash. See the docs for details.